# How to get TEST ETH?

Tags: test

I'm learning how to develop on the ethereum network. I'm currently going thru a tutorial I found, and I need to get test eth. Every faucet/website I've tried ( even from the official ethereum.org/documentation website ) either ends up giving me an error, or just nothing happens. It's so frustrating to be stuck on something so seemingly meaningless.

Is it necessary for me to get test eth when I'm still just learning? Because as of right now, I have to wait 1 hour to give it another try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got 0.1 test ETH from this Goerli faucet sent to my Metamask account's Goerli network a few minutes ago, but you need to sign up for Alchemy first. Alchemy is a node service provider that if you want to develop on the Ethereum network, you will eventually use.

See:

https://goerlifaucet.com/

https://www.alchemy.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot! <3 It was so frustrating to be stuck on a small problem. Wish you all the best ! 
```0.05
GoerliETH
$81.59
USD
```
I'm rich now :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always setup your own chain using ganache :)